# Why does the ICANN Registrar list show variants of the same company multiple times?

Tags: domains, dns, domain-registration, domain-registrar, icann

While browsing the ICANN list of accredited registrars:
https://www.icann.org/registrar-reports/accredited-list.html

I've noticed that a couple of companies are registered multiple times and multiple registered links redirect to the same company. For example, there are numerous entries for `DropCatch.com`. There are a bunch of other companies doing the same thing.

From what I understand, it costs a couple thousand dollars to appear on this list. Why are these companies registering multiple times?

Comment: Looks like someone trying to take advantage of a loophole in case they lose their accreditation. Notice that they registered 400 different similar domains (with only 1 number difference), and also registered 400 different LLCs in the State of Colorado. Associated sites have an "F" rating with the BBB too. I'd say, buyer beware when they see something sketchy looking like this.

Comment: I also noticed that the particular site, http://DropCatch.com tries to snatch up expired domains during the "drop". It could be that by having more instances in the drop, they can tilt the process in their favour. 

I've also noticed that a ton of companies on the list redirect to http://www.networksolutions.com/. They might be doing what you talk about.

Comment: Seems likely. I thought registrations were only limited by the number of socket connects per IP address, but all their domains seem to be on the same IP... I'm sure it's related though, with the added benefit of safeguarding accreditation. I sent an inquiry to a contact at ICANN to see what's up with this. It certainly makes finding other accredited registrars more difficult to find having to scroll past 400 listing for the same organization, and I think could possibly devalue what accreditation means to the public.

Comment: Very interesting question now that I visited the site and read the comments. There are scammers in every corner. As well, those who try and snatch-up dropped domains make a killing so they are going to do anything to protect their interest including coughing up $2k 400 times is chump change to them. I would assume their domain names are hosted- did not look- and that they operate off of another set of IP addresses- likely throw-aways. Telcos do not mind changing IP addresses at the drop of a hat if you got the money. It can be almost instantaneous. Kind of a dark secret of the industry.

Comment: @dan: Did you hear back anything?

Comment: Registries limit connections per registrars. So if a company has multiple " shell "  companies, each accredited as registrars, then it has many more connections than others " single player"  registrars. But this is old game, so registries in the mean time introduced rules about  " group of registrars"  controlled by a same given company.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of instances where actions taken by ICANN need the support or consultation of the Registrars Stakeholder Group. Without someone from ICANN coming on here and confirming officially the reason for the duplicate records I suspect that it could be similar to a shareholder type of situation where each accredited registrar entry has one vote and the more entries the more effect you can have on the direction of ICANN.

I admit this is a hypothesis but from my basic reading of the ICANN bylaws it looks to be that could be a big factor in it. I would say it also has something to do with protection against de-accreditation but I would say it is probably less to do with that than many people think as it would be a simple matter for ICANN to de-accredit all entries a single entity has (such as what enom has as obvious duplications). As for a large number of entries which trace back to NameBright these d appear to be deliberate attempts to circumvent any grievance or de-registration measures as these companies are listed as partners of NameBright and that is all they do.

It may also be possible that at some time in the past there really was a company named Echo Domain which was bought by NameBright and amalgamated as well as amalgamating their ICANN accreditation.

I would say that all of these cases could be seen in the ICANN accreditation list and I have to say it is highly doubtful all duplications are attempts at using a loophole for re-accreditation protection.

Answer (score 2):

When domains expire/drop they become available to 'catch' and reregister using backordering before they are released for general public to purchase. If a backorder is placed by anyone (including resellers) then the registrar which accepted the backorder get to put their name in the hat. At the time of expiry a registrar name is picked out of the hat and they win the domain on behalf of their customer. Being setup with multiple registrars gets you more chances of winning as your name is in the hat more times (albeit variations of your name which may be for subsidiary companies). With this in mind the registrars most likely to win a backorder will be those with the most registrar entries at ICANN (and also paying the most fees therefore).

Personally I think ICANN should only accept one registrar application per group of companies so that the catch is fair. Typically domain resellers make huge markups on the domains they catch and in turn that money is put to keep buying more registrar applications to ensure they are always getting the best chances in backorder. This is just one of their strategies but it is effective. Oftentimes domain resellers will use scripts to place bids into auctions right at the last second too (this practice is known as sniping on ebay). Additionally since ICANN decisions require the support of the registrars, with the majority of registrars being domain resellers as a result of this method it will prove very difficult for ICANN to ever change this abusive practice.